# Is it possible to insert text from a Google spreadsheet into a text box in a Google document?

Tags: google-sheets, google-docs, google-drawings

I need to insert text into a template that contains multiple text boxes in a variety of orientations. I can do that by inserting a text box from Google Drawings into a Google Doc and formatting it to the correct angle.

Is there any way of merging text from a Google spreadsheet into its respective text box?

The idea here is to automate the process so I don't have to type in 40+ text boxes for each new project.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can tell it's not possible.

Any text in a drawing object is inaccessible from a script, and this is the only way to perform a mail merge. I can't find any other way to rotate text in a Google doc.

There is [a question on Stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8996422/modifying-a-drawing-using-google-apps-script) relating to this, and an open [issue](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=1054) with Google.

The response from the Google devs seems to be that it sounds like a good idea, but it won't happen soon.